# Divide balls in cells - Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

We divide $n$ distinguishable balls in $k$ distinguishable cells. Such that in every cell is the same amount of balls. Define $B(n,k)$ as the number of different possibilities to do this. (cells could be empty)

When $n$ is odd, $B(n,k)=0$. Therefore, to make more sense, we will add a copy of ball 1. Determine an expression for the number of possibilities, expressed in well chosen terms of $B(i,j)$. And compute $B(n,k)$ as function of $n$ and $k$ with help of exponential generating functions.

Can somebody give me some help to solve this problem properly, I am not very used with exp. gen. functions en combinatroics?

Comment: In the first place, $n$ should be a multiple of $k$, if every cell has to receive the same number of balls. If $n$ is an odd multiple of an odd $k$ then $B(n,k)\ne0$.